# TinyMCE Pop Up Showing 404 Not Found

Tags: tinymce, http-status-code-404

Currently I am developing a website, and using TinyMCE as text editor for the admin backend. Overall it works well, but for several buttons like Link, Image, Media, or any button which should showing pop-up, the pop-up keep showing 404 Not Found.

I don't know what's the problem. I am sure I have included tinyMce.js, jQuery.tinyMce.js & tinyMCe.css.
Am I missing something?

This is script I added to my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    ///// TINYMCE EDITOR /////
    jQuery('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url : 'js/plugins/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    skin : "themepixels",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    inlinepopups_skin: "themepixels",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent,indent,blockquote,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,help,code,|,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,removeformat,|,charmap,media,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "assets/css/plugins/tinymce.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
    });


    jQuery('.editornav a').click(function(){
        jQuery('.editornav li.current').removeClass('current');
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('current');
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('visual'))
            jQuery('#elm1').tinymce().show();
        else
            jQuery('#elm1').tinymce().hide();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

After I check my console, it showing this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:82/indocreweb/backend/business/assets/css/plugins/tinymce.css

The path should be localhost:82/indocreweb/assets/css/plugins/tinymce.css ;
localhost:82/indocreweb/backend/business is the path for the page that using tinyMCE.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Try add some code. Give as much information as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out~ Even though it's quite awkward to answer my own question. Well, hopefully you won't do the same stupid mistakes like I did.

So based on web console, tracked down each page that couldn't be found and made sure they all exist (in my case it happened because part of some plugins was renamed wrong). Once I made sure they all can be found, the pop up works just fine.

Comment: It's fine here (on SO) to answer your own question. Also, I'm glad you eventually found the help you needed. ;)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the upload link was wrong, I changed the server URL, but forgot to change the tincymce setting.